# Texturing a sphere with Three.js does'nt work on smartphones

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some troubles using Three.js. I want to apply a texture on a sphere (an image). My code works without any problem... until I try it on a smartphone. I try to look for the bug with Firefox and its remote debugger, but I did not find the issue. Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./sphere.js"></script>
        <style>
            html, body, #container {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"></div>

        <script>
            init();
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

and :

```
var renderer, scene, camera, mesh;

function init() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var width = container.offsetWidth;
    var height = container.offsetHeight;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, width/height, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);
    scene.add(camera);

    var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 16, 16);

    var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
    var f = function(img) {
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        texture.image = img;

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, overdraw: true});
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(mesh);
        render();
        animate();
    }
    loader.load('sphere.jpg', f);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.003;
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

What do I do wrong?

If you want to see the code in action, you can go [here](http://tests.jeremyheleine.com/sphere/sphere.html). Note that the problem is here with both WebGLRenderer and CanvasRenderer.

Comment: Could it be that your sphere.jpg is not a power of two and your smartphone can't load it? Try 1024x1024 as a reasonable texture size.

Comment: @GuyGood: Indeed, there is no problem with a smaller image (2048×1024). Thanks for this idea! Now the problem is: can we change this behavior? :/

Comment: No, i don't think so, you can at least try 4096/2048, just keep the size a power of 2. Just keep in mind that even high end graphics cards have a limit on single texture size. Also, i can't see why this small sphere would need anything larger than 1024² ;)

Comment: @GuyGood: This small sphere is just a test. Obviously, large images are useless for it, but it is useful for the library I created ([Photo Sphere Viewer](http://jeremyheleine.com/#photo-sphere-viewer)) where the user can create panoramas as big as he want. I will try to resize the images to have a power of 2. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a repost: The problem is solved by using power of two texture sizes.